# How to bring the journal name at the top in IEEEtran?

Tags: ieeetran

I am new to Latex. At the top of my paper, i want to bring the name of conference/journal. I don't know what should i call it..i have already tried to use `header` but header is something different.

i want to bring the top line (**"JOURNAL OF LATEX CLASS FILES, VOL. 11, NO. 4, DECEMBER 2012"**) as shown in the image below: [image].

Currently i am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %used for header
\pagestyle{fancy} %also used for header
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[all,graph]{xy}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{comment}

 \title{Affect of Motion Direction}
\author
{\IEEEauthorblockN{SKM}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Faculty of Electrical Engineering\\
University of XYZ\\
skm@mail.com}
}
\markboth{IEEE Transactions on \LaTeX}{SKM: My IEEE article}    

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\input{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Attention shift, Eye movement, Spatial attention.
\end{keywords}

\input{introduction}
\section{REVIEW OF EXISTING MATERIAL}
\input{exp_method}    
\section{EXPERIMENTAL RESULTS}
\section{GENERAL DISCUSSION}

\bibliography{refer.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
\markboth{IEEE Transactions on \LaTeX}{Skm: My article name}
```

A full example (please you do the same for your future questions)

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cite,graphicx,amssymb,amsfonts,booktabs,multirow,array,comment}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage[all,graph]{xy}
\title{Affect of Motion Direction}
\author
{\IEEEauthorblockN{SKM}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Faculty of Electrical Engineering\\
University of XYZ\\
skm@mail.com}
}
\markboth{IEEE Transactions on \LaTeX}{SKM: My IEEE article}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it is bringing me `Skm: My article name` on the right side and `IEEE Transactions on` on the left side...and they appear only on the 2nd page..not on the first page

Comment: @skm Yes that's IEEE style. It should do that.

Comment: i updated my comment...they appear from the 2nd page not from the first page above the title

Comment: @skm I think you are used to this site. Without your code there is not much we can guess.

Comment: if i remove `conference` from the line `\documentclass[12pt,conference]{IEEEtran}` then i am able to get the desired results only for the first page. But on the next page it appears as a `header` alongwith a `horizontal line`

Comment: @skm If you don't include a proper code starting from `\documentclass{} ... \end{document}` I can't help you. Each time you include new info. For conferences use `ieeeconf` class. IEEE conferences don't have conference name as headers (unless it is a compsoc conference)

Comment: Ok, i have posted the whole code which i am using.

Comment: I saw that you have updated your answer with my code and put its result also. The problem is that the results are ok for the first page...but for the second page it appears as a `Header` with bigger size and a horizontal line below it.